# Undo Send - works on some computers but not others. Is Chrome required?

Tags: gmail

Does it only work with Chrome?  Not FireFox!?

Undo Send - works on some computers but not others.  Is Chrome required?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to this option then make sure you have enabled JavaScript and no extensions or add-ons interfere with it (eg. try it in incognito mode) - and to answer your question: no, it's not mandatory to have a Chrome browser.

[image: 0]